# Using CGAL Triangulation to get d-dimensional convex hull

Tags: c++, cgal, triangulation, convex-hull, n-dimensional

As the title suggests, I need to compute the convex hull of a number of d-dimensional points (where the number of points is usually around 20 and d is around 50). I spent a good day or so reading the documentation and searching the net, but it seems everything is either outdated (still using convex_hull_d), or only concerns dimensions <= 3.

The documentation site redirects from "dD Convex Hulls and Delaunay Triangulations" to "dD Triangulation". My problem is that I can't find a simple implementation of a convex hull retrieval function there. Although I'm pretty sure this is most likely done in 1 line of code.

How can I compute the convex hull of a d-dimensional convex using CGAL?

Comment: As such, I'm afraid your question will get closed. Could you edit question and add some relevant code. Even outdated, even a small snippet, but this is necessary to start, so people can see exactly the problem. And if possible the compiler command and any error messages. And direct links on the correspondent doc pages you refer to.

Comment: To be honest there is no relevant code, because the aforementioned convex_hull_d command is not usable anymore, as can be seen in: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_d/index.html#Chapter_dD_Convex_Hulls_and_Delaunay_Triangulations. And finding the appropriate alternative command is exactly what I´m after.

Comment: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation/index.html#title16 "Traversing the Facets of the Convex Hull"?